# How to generate a PDF in a ASP API and send it to my Cordova application?

Tags: asp.net, api, cordova

First sorry for my english, I'm a french guy so I don't speak it perfectly don't be to fierce with me ;)

Presently I'm working on a smartphone application developed with cordova, in this application we got the notion of order and I need to create a way for the user to download a PDF with his order details.
For the project, we are using an ASP API, so I think the best way to do it it's to ask to the API to do it for me but still that after some research I havn't find any clue to generate a PDF sendable to my application on the API. Or perhaps that I've miss understood some stuff, but I'm a little bit stuck currently ^^'

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  understood your question right, the easiest approach is to generate PDF file using server side coding and store it in server. You can then access the PDF file from server and store it in device using cordova file transfer and cordova file plugins.

Comment: Yeah, I want to generate the PDF server side (I don't need to store it) and downlaod it on the device (I don't know how).

Comment: @Coloniseur thats what i have answered on my post. If you dont want to store pdf on server side, you can make ajax call from the cordova app and get the byte data of the pdf file and can generate the pdf in the device using cordova file plugin. Also you can open the file using fileopener cordova plugin

Comment: Ok so, can you tell me how did I generate the PDF to get his byte data? ^^'

Comment: @Coloniseur I was trying to answer the question from mobile app perspective. If you are looking for server side code to generate PDF files, you may have look at this link - http://forums.asp.net/t/1963542.aspx?Free+libraries+SDK+to+generate+Word+and+PDF+file as i dont have much expertise in ASP APIs

Comment: Thank, I wil take a look at this! Hope that i will success ;P

Comment: @Coloniseur Gud luck. Happy coding